# Shell session management in jcabi ssh?

Tags: java, ssh, jcabi

How would I or do I need to close the session when I use the jcabi ssh library to execute a shell command when I do something like the following? I suspect I'm running out of sockets when I pair this in a looping scenario.

```
`Shell shell = new SSH(server, 22, "ubuntu", ReadPemFile());
return new Shell.Plain(shell).exec("some shell command");`
```

Thank you. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Good question (I'm one of the authors of jcabi-ssh)... We [disconnect](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-ssh/blob/1.5.2/src/main/java/com/jcabi/ssh/Execution.java#L128) but I'm not sure about closing. Would be great if you can submit an issue to GitHub and we'll try to figure out what's going on and maybe fix the bug.